# why firebase + ionic (angular1) freezes when sharing coordinatess between 2 users?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Problem: if in my db more than 40-50 users, then it start freezes and lugs, at any db queries. But if i have less than 40-50 users, problem goes away.

Description: 
In "connections" i get child with username/key/coords/etc, in "keys" i have users (friends) which should get my coords (loop through "keys", taking "key" of user and send coords to this user in "connections")
PS. firebase free version, in restrictions:  ~100 Simultaneous connections, but i haven't evet 3 simultaneous connections.

How the user looks in DB:
[image]

[image: How the user looks in DB:]

Statistics: 
[image]

Comment: Does your firebase subscription support the size of data you would share with 40-50 users?  Maybe you're just not paying for that much space?

Comment: i dont think so, i added statistics pic to the post, there is nothing to worry about

Comment: Is there a magic number at which things go south or is it just that range generally?

Comment: Also could we see the code that's requesting the information on person 1 and then sending to person 2? And have you used log statements to see where in that process it freezes? Like is it querying or sending?